# Sort numpy array by datetime objects

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, numpy

I have two numpy arrays: `date_month` of the form

```
array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 12, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 1, 12, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 12, 0)], dtype=object)
```

and `emission_each_month` of the form

```
array([5,7,3])
```

The entry 5 of `emission_each_month` belongs to the timestamp (2013, 1, 1, 12, 0), 7 belongs to (2013, 9, 1, 12, 0), 3 belongs to (2013, 5, 1, 12, 0).
(In reality my data is much bigger)

I would like to have my data sorted by date. How do I that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) to get the indexes of the sorted array of datetime object , and then use the returned indices to sort the array - `emission_each_month` . Example -

```
In [66]: import datetime

In [67]: import numpy as np

In [68]: n = np.array([5,7,3])

In [69]: d = np.array([datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 12, 0)])

In [72]: n[np.argsort(d)]
Out[72]: array([5, 3, 7])
```